# How does electricity flow if circuit is not complete?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, electromagnetism, physics, field

https://youtu.be/oI_X2cMHNe0

What is he saying at 13:20? How can bulb glow if the circuit is not complete?

Answer (score 1):

Look at 16:00. Basically if you disconnect far end(or both ends) of circuit, you will be left with basically two capacitors, hence when voltage initially applied capacitors will charge and during that period light buld will glow. That circuit is not complete, but it kinda is.

Otherwise antennas wouldn't work, would they?

Comment: hm, antennas are yet another thing than charges stored on capacitors

Answer (score 0):

As many people pointed out, this video is misleading. The bulb will eventually pass a current of V/R there V is the battery terminal voltage, and R is the resistance of the remaining circuit (usually dominated by the bulb resistance). This in not the current that will flow 1m/c seconds after the switch is closed. If we have a pair of parallel wires, they form a transmission line. This will have a characteristic impedance. The moment you apply a voltage between these wires, a current of V / Rc will flow, where Rc is the characteristic impedance. You can think of the 2 parallel wires as a series of inductors (the wire inductance) and capacitors (formed be the conductive wires as the capacitor plates separated by the space between the wires). The electrical potential travels alone the wires at the propagation velocity (this is determined by the losses in the wire and dielectric, but will be close to the speed of light, and in a totally lossless system it will equal the speed of light). If the other end of the line is open, then current will eventually stop flowing. If the other end is shorted, impedance looking into the line will eventually become equal to the resistance of the wires. So the simple answer to your question in that the current that flows initially is charging up the capacitance of the transmission line formed by the parallel wires.